# Android application won't launch on device

Tags: android, apk, android-activity

I have developed an Android application using Eclipse which works perfectly on the Android Virtual Device or when running it on my smartphone using Eclipse + USB Debugging mode enabled.

However, when I install the application on my phone using a signed apk file which resided on the sd card and try to launch it I get a "Activity not found - lsp.workshop" error, and the app won't start (lsp.workshop is the application package name).

the AndroidManifest.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lsp.workshop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <activity
            android:name=".TwitterLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="twitter" />

                <data android:host="log" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Why isn't it named something.apk?

Comment: lsp.workshop is the package (directories under src folder) containing my source files, not the name of the apk file which indeed is somtething.apk

Comment: Oh. Since it says "Activity not found", are you sure you have .TwitterLogin?

Comment: Yes, I have TwitterLogin.java file. It does launch on the AVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two intent filters instead of one solved the problem:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="twitter" android:host="log" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

The emulator and android with a debugger attached can behave differently then when you start an app normally. The timing is different (influences multithreading and race conditions) and other things may be affected as well.

But just to be sure:

Did you list the activity within your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Is the spelling really correct?

If those things are not the problem, then could you show some code (how do you start the activity? with an intent?) and maybe the manifest file ?

Comment: I have edited my original message with the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

When you export your apk,be sure to name it -something.apk ,ie just put the ".apk" at the end when you export the application (y)